# Embedded resource does not load in listview in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin.forms

[UPDATE]

So, by using the provided [Dependency Injector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.dependencyservice?view=xamarin-forms) I have found a really easy way to fix this and it's loading the thing from the assets in Android. 
I will have to seek how to do this in iOS but for now it's not a big concern.

What is more concerning, however, is that the single cell isn't displaying as it should.

The revised (and relevant) bit of XAML is as follows:

```
<ViewCell>
   <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
     <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start"></Label>
     <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
       <Label Text="{Binding Email}" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Start"></Label>
       <Image Source="{Binding image.Source}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"></Image>
     </StackLayout>
  </StackLayout>
</ViewCell>
```

So the current display is thus: 
-> Row 1 = Perfect
-> Row 2 : Email=Perfect, Image = Only a small fraction visible

I suspect this has to do with the layouts but I have no idea why it's doing this.

Suggestions, please! 
[OLD POST]
I have a XAML file that displays properly in the Android preview pane except for an image element. This is the XAML I am using:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App3"
             x:Class="App3.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="WPF test for POD" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <Entry Placeholder="Email address" Keyboard="Email"></Entry>
        <Entry Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="True" Text="WobblyDobbly"></Entry>
        <Button x:Name="BtnSignIn" Text="Sign In" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Clicked="BtnSignIn_Clicked">
        </Button>
        <StackLayout x:Name="slUserInfo" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Entry Placeholder="Name" x:Name="txtName" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Entry>
            <Entry Placeholder="Email" x:Name="txtEmail" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Keyboard="Email"></Entry>
            <Button Text="Add to list" x:Name="btnAddToList" Clicked="btnAddToList_Clicked" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="lvItems" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!--
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" Detail="{Binding Email}">

                    </TextCell>
                    -->
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Email}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"></Label>
                            <Image Source="{Binding image.Source}" HorizontalOptions="End"> </Image>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>               

            </ListView.ItemTemplate>            

        </ListView>
        <Button x:Name="btnAddItem" Text="Add..." HorizontalOptions="Start" Clicked="btnAddItem_Clicked">

        </Button>
    </StackLayout> 
</ContentPage>
```

In the backend, I have these classes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App3
{
    class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public Image image { get; set; }
        public Item( int AnId, string AName, string AnEmail)
        {
            Id = AnId;
            Name = AName;
            Email = AnEmail;
        }
    }

    class ItemList : ObservableCollection<Item>
    {
        public void Add(string Name, string Email,string AssignedImage, int Id = 0)
        {
            int ActualID = Id;
            Item item = new Item(Id, Name, Email);
            if (ActualID == 0)
            {
                ActualID = NextId();
            }
            item.image = new Image();
            item.image.Source = ImageSource.FromResource(AssignedImage);
            Add(item);
        }

        public int NextId()
        {
            int CurrentCount = Count;
            return ++CurrentCount;
        }
    }
}
```

When using the UWP project, everything work correctly.
However, when I run this on Android - just as in the preview - it doesn't display the image.

My MainPage.xaml.cs looks like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App3
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private ItemList model = new ItemList();
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lvItems.ItemsSource = model;
            model.Add("Andrea", "email@email.com", "App3.arrow_left.png");
            slUserInfo.IsVisible = false;
        }

        private void BtnSignIn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnAddItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            slUserInfo.IsVisible = true; 
        }

        private void btnAddToList_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            model.Add(txtName.Text, txtEmail.Text,"App3.arrow_left.png");
            txtName.Text = "";
            txtEmail.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

The image is marked as EmbeddedResource and is located in /Resources under the common project.

When I run it as UWP, the image displays correctly. When I run it as Android app, the image doesn't show at all. There is no special code in the Android app.
I am sure I am doing something wrong, can you please point me in the right direction?

P.S. This is my first full day dedicated to Xamarin, so please don't avoid the basic questions as chances are it's something simple that I have overlooked.

Comment: A couple of questions: how big is the image?  If it's too large, Android sometimes fails to scale it down so displays nothing.  Also, what it the resource Id of the image as an embedded resource?

Comment: No it's quite small. To make sure it'd load, I picked off a png that we use as button glyph.

Comment: I am not sure what the Id is, I would've thought that Xamarin would do the heavy lifting and arrange things for me.